# routing error with :username in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a Rails 3 question. I want to get my users controller show page to have the app.com/people/username url.

Route

```
resources :users  
match "/people/:username" => 'users#show', :as => :profile
```

It's work, but if username starts with "." (dot) I have an error:

**No route matches "/people/.G"**

And

```
<%= link_to current_user.username, profile_path(current_user.username) %>
```

raise an exception:

**No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show", :username=>".G"}**

Sorry for my English, Thanks!

Comment: what are you using for your link_to paths here? How do you format the "username" param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think starting with `.` is supported by default in rails routes. You can do something like

```
match "/people/:username" => 'users#show', :as => :profile, :username => /[\.a-zA-Z0-9_]+/
```

The above regex will match `., a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _` as valid characters for the username.

Comment: /[\.\%a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+/    is the regexp i used to allow all possible characters. And it is working for me.