# Correct routing for short url by username in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I am trying to replace user profile views of the sort

`/users/1`

with

`/username`

I'm aware this means I'll need to check for collisions of various kinds.  I've consulted the following similar SO questions:

- [Ruby on rails routing matching username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611649/ruby-on-rails-routing-matching-username)
- [customize rails url with username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269885/username-in-url-with-rails-routes)
- [Routing in Rails making the Username an URL:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048063/routing-in-rails-making-the-username-an-url)
- [routing error with :username in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204057/routing-error-with-username-in-url)

Here are the various failed routes.rb route definitions I've tried, and associated errors:

1. `match "/:username"  => "users#show", via: "get"`

   Here's the error:

   ```
   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

   Couldn't find User without an ID

   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `show'
   ```

   Here is my corresponding users_controller:

   ```
   6 def show
   7   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   8 end
   ```
2. `match "/:username" => 'users#show', :as => :profile`

   Same error as above.
3. `match "/:username", :controller => "users/:id", :action => 'show'`

   ```
    Routing Error

    uninitialized constant Users

    Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
   ```
4. `match '/:username', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'`

   Same error as 1.
5. `match '/:username', to: 'users/:id', via: 'show'`

   Server does not start.
6. `match "/:username" => redirect("/users/:id")`

   Error:

   ```
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

    Couldn't find User with id=:id
   ```

Any idea why my routing is not working the same way that everyone else who asks this question's is?

**Update**

Just to take this issue out of the comments and put it in the question more cleanly.  After making the change by @Ryan Bigg below, I had a routing problem in my redirect to profile when a new one is created.  Here's my create code:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        flash[:success] = "Thank you for signing up."
        redirect_to ('/'+@user.username)
        #redirect_to @user, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end
```

And here is my user.rb

```
def to_param
    self.username
    #username
end
```

However, the commented out redirect, which I think should work with the to_param update, doesn't work, while the ugly hackish one above it does.  Why is the to_param overwrite, [which worked for other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611649/ruby-on-rails-routing-matching-username?lq=1), not working on my app?  My #update and #edit methods are also not working, as their redirects go to "users/1/edit" instead of "username/edit" if overwriting to_param doesn't take care of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is correct, but  isn't working because you're still attempting to do something like this inside your controller:

```
User.find(params[:username])
```

When you should instead be doing this:

```
User.find_by_username!(params[:username])
```

The first one will attempt to find by the primary key of your table, where the second one will, correctly, query on the username field instead.

Comment: I see. Can you explain to me what's wrong with the current controller style? How should I be thinking of the other correctly?

Comment: Ryan, you've very thoroughly answered my question, but can I follow up by asking how to name a redirect route?  I'm trying this, which isn't working, under my create user method:   `@user = User.new(params[:user])  if @user.save
 redirect_to @user.username`

Comment: Nevermind---for anyone else doing this, I solved it with ` redirect_to '/' + @user.username`

Comment: @Mittenchops: That's quite ugly. What I would do is override to_param on the user model to return just `username` and then just `redirect_to @user` will redirect to the correct path.

Comment: I've updated to follow your comment here---can you point me to why this isn't working?  `redirect_to @user` tries to redirect to nil.

Comment: @Mittenchops: It would be redirecting to nil only if you had not set `@user` yet, or purposely set it to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the update for to_params, the bottom of the routes file needs the following line:

`resources :users, :path => '/'`